# Can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby
I am trying to create a simple script that will convert a given number to roman numerals (old style roman numerals)

I am unable to understand why I get the "can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)"

```
def convert_to_roman number
  romans_array = [[1000,'M'],[500,'D'],[100,'C'],[50,'L'],[10,'X'],[5,'V'][1,'I']]
  converted_array = []

  romans_array.each do |rom_num|
    num = rom_num[0]
    letter = rom_num[1]

    if number > num
      times = number / num
      roman_letter = letter*times
      converted_array.push(roman_letter)
      number = number % num
    end
  end
  converted_array.join()
end

number = ''
puts 'please write a number and I will convert it to old style Roman numerals :)'
puts 'p.s. to exit this program simply hit enter on an empty line, or type 0 and enter :)'

while number != 0
  number = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts convert_to_roman number
end
```

My code is at:
https://github.com/stefanonyn/ruby-excercises/blob/master/roman_numerals.rb

You will see that at the end of the file commented out there is an old revision of the code, which actually does work but has a lot of repetition.

I would appreciate if someone could clarify why I get the error described above.
Please don't write the code for me, I am trying to learn Ruby, I would appreciate just some support in moving to the next step.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma in your array

```
  romans_array = [[1000,'M'],[500,'D'],[100,'C'],[50,'L'],[10,'X'],[5,'V'][1,'I']]
                                                                          ^ here
```

This error is definitely not all that helpful, but the reason that it is appearing is that to the interpreter it looks like you are attempting to access a range of indexes in the [5,'V'] array for the last element. However the index's that are being provided go from 1 to 'I' which of course makes no sense. If it had been written `[5,'V'][1,1]` the last element of the array would be ['V'], which might have been even more confusing to debug!